# How can i check if pin already exist in table and redirect

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if pin  already exist in table. if existed it should echo message and redirect to another page.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$test = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$test[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}

if($test["number_update"] == 1) { 
echo 'Pin Already in Use, Please Login';
header("location:compet_start.php");
} else {

mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num', number_update='1' WHERE Pin= '$Pin'")
        or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO pinlog (TableName,pin,id,TIME_UPDATED) VALUES('Pin','$Pin','$num','$date')")
        or die(mysql_error()); 

header("location:compet_applicant.php?pin=$Pin");
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second and the third line? The third just replaces the second, what's the idea?

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Comment: It appears you are trying to get US to write you application for you. _From looking at your question history._ Are you going to share your wages with us as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) {
 echo "Pin exists";
}
else {
  echo "Pin does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you can have only 1 record `WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'` then you can just:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin'");
if($test = mysql_fetch_array($result) && $test["number_update"] == 1) { 
echo 'Pin Already in Use, Please Login';
header("location:compet_start.php");
} else {
...
```

And in your question you wrote *I want to check if pin already exist in table* so if you just need to check if it is exists you can remove `&& $test["number_update"] == 1` and simplify the condition :

```
if($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

**Comment** There is no reason to `echo` before `header("location` because user will never see that `echo`ed text

```
//echo 'Pin Already in Use, Please Login'; <-- this should be deleted
header("location:compet_start.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only if a row exists or not you could also take a look at the EXISTS subqueries of mySQL.
It would return true or false and is more clear, it will be also faster than fetching all the answers.

```
 "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  = '$Pin')"
```

See here: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: In general that is sound advice, but if you're preventing duplicates anyway, 'all' the answers are just that one pin.

Comment: Yes indeed. It was more general advice on the pros of using EXISTS instead of normal queries for checking. However a boolean would also be shorter even from a single table row.